# System checks for disk drive error every time it boots

Tags: disk-management

When my disk space for the ubuntu installation partition was getting low, from a live cd, I used gparted to increase its volume capacity, by deleting another partition and merging it to the ubuntu partition.

Since then, I am always receiving disk checking for errors at boot screen for my partitions.

What seems to be causing this and how can I fix it?

#### Update

Here is my boot.log if it provides few insight

```
fsck from util-linux 2.19.1
fsck from util-linux 2.19.1
/dev/sda1 was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
ubuntu: clean, 501325/1310720 files, 2958455/5242880 blocks
/dev/sda1: 241/51272 files (3.3% non-contiguous), 73541/102400 blocks
mountall: fsck /boot [358] terminated with status 1
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
...
```

/dev/sda1 is a separate grub partition for my dual OS's

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to let it complete at least once. fsck is a legitimate health-check, and it's the "Right Thing" to do.

that said, if you ARE letting it complete, and it's still running every time you reboot, check the SMART results in the Disk Utility application (disk could be going bad), or adjust the frequency of disk checks with a command like:

```
sudo tune2fs -c 50 /dev/sda1
```

be sure to change the device to your actual device name, and feel free to adjust the count as well.

Comment: Yes, I am letting it complete and Smart results show "Disk in healthy"

Comment: Is there a way to check the boot log, so may be you guys to see what actually is the problem

Comment: fish around for any likely looking suspects in /var/log/, it can't hurt

Comment: I have updated with the boot log. Please see

Answer (score 0):

To disable file system integrity check for  forever. Type following command

```
sudo tune2fs -c -1 /dev/sda
```

Where sda is your HDD.

Comment: I would suggest to not stop the integrity check but to look into why it is checking it. The partition might have a problem (inode related, file corruption, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Your drive (partition /dev/sda1) is not being cleanly unmounted. In layman's terms: Your computer isn't shutting down that partition properly, and as a result your drive may have suffered damage - that's why this happens.

Comment: How can i fix it?

Comment: Are you shutting down your computer properly? Also, knowing all the partitions on your system might be helpful (i.e. sda1: boot, sda2: home or whatever)

Comment: Yes, I used to.

Comment: And by 'used to' you mean?

Comment: I don't have that system anymore. I installed Debian.

Comment: What are your partitions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7845/discussion-between-whiskers75-and-starx)